# Exception from javax.xml.ws.Provider<Source>

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-ee-7

I have created a stateless EJB annotated with the **@WebServiceProvider** annotatoin and made it point to a WSDL file I created (contract first web services) and implemented the Interface **javax.xml.ws.Provider**. the web service is correctly started in JBoss and I can consume it using SoapUI.

I would like to enhance the web service a little bit so that it gives error responses back to SoapUI, my ideal situation would be throwing a RuntimeException from the invoke() method and see it's stacktrace back in SoapUI log, but I cannot nail it.

I also tried returning a **javax.xml.transform.Source** object but I see nothing in the SoapUI log. Reading a little bit I came across this phrase on this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24965/faults.htm#WSADV623):

> The faults are returned to the sender only if request/response
> messaging is in use. If a Web service operation is configured as
> one-way, the SOAP fault is not returned to the sender, but stored for
> further processing.

So I guess the answer to my question is to have a request/response messaging in use but how can I do that is it something to configure in the WSDL or in the Java classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler than what I thought, I simply added an output parameter to the operation in the WSDL file. at this point if an exception is thrown from the invoke() method a  response is sent back to the webservice consumer.